# Multiple close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When going through the review queue, I occasionally encounter questions that have close votes citing different reasons. But when I look at an already closed question, I always see just a single reason being cited for closing the question.

This lead me to the question, if the reasons for closing a question are not unanimous, how is the close reason that gets displayed with a closed question determined? Is it a majority-vote, or the reason of the last person voting to close, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 5 users vote, I believe it's majority vote gets the reason. However, if a moderator closes, it's always the moderator's reason.

Comment: And if there's a tie (e.g. 1 OT, 2 NARQ 2 NC), then the last vote wins.

Comment: so that's mod vote FTW?

Comment: @GlenH7: I would say it is "mod vote trumps regular users", as it is also for the number of votes (1 mod versus 5 users)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - I was making a bit of joke; sorry it wasn't more clear.  The mods do have instant close powers.  Several of the mods have commented that one of the things they miss about being "regular" users is the non-binding vote. Marginal quality questions are the hardest since their vote doesn't allow the community to review the question.